# Angular JS Routing with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing, angularjs-ng-click

I have problem with angular js that I am not able to solve, so I need your help...
This is my code:

```
angular.module("test2", ["ng.route"])

.config(function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider.when ("/contratti",
{
templateUrl:"eleconContrattiAngular.jsp",
controller: "goCTRL"
}

);
});

<a href="#/contratti/rowId=rowId=123">dettaglio</a> `
```

This will be my configuration with a link... How can i transform this link in a button? 
I tried with this:

```
function goCTRL($scope,$location) {
    $scope.goBack = function (hash) {
            $location.path(hash); 
    }       
    }    
 <button ng-click="goBack('#/contratti')">BACK</button>
```

But it didn't even work...

Answer (score 0):

When using $location.path, you don't want to include the hash (#).  According to the description for [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location), the path will always start with a forward slash, or a forward slash will be added to the start of the path.  That means with your example, you are trying to go to www.yoursite.com/#/#/contratti.  Since that isn't a valid path, it's not working.

The easy fix for this is to take out the hash from the function call and see if it works.  So in the button, it would be *ng-click="goBack('/contratti')"*.

Comment: It also doesn't look like you're registering the controller or possibly adding the controller to a module depending on how your code's broken out...with the way you have it set up, try adding `module.controller('goCTRL', ['$scope', '$location', controller]);` after the end of the function goCTRL (...){...}

Comment: <!-- function goCTRL($scope,$location) {
        $scope.goBack = function (hash) {$location.path(hash);}         
                                                          }    
     module.controller('goCTRL',['$scope','$location',controller]);-->

@lucky.hooligan Like this?

Comment: Should be something like that, though you will need to include `var module = angular.module('test2')` at the top of the file.  The more conventional way would be 
`var myApp = angular.module('test2');

myApp.controller('goCTRL', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
      $scope.goBack = function (hash) {
            $location.path(hash); 
    }
}]);`

Comment: .. Nothing... I think i will stay with the href configuration. Thanks a lot for the support!